# How can I attach an event handler after loading an external page with an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a service which allows users to create teams and challenges, as well as individual accounts. Each team and challenge has a unique "ownerID" and each user has a "userID". The main user splash page consists of three accordions: Teams, Challenges and Settings, which, upon selection, display a series of buttons. After clicking a button, an empty div is populated with data from a separate page. And then I run into the aforementioned problem. After loading the external page data for challenges, which contains a drop down list and either a user join or team join button dependent on the selection. The problem is, I want to be able to click on either button and then call a function, but, I can't say:

```
$('#userJoin').on("click", function() {
                var challengeID = $('#challengeSelect').val();
                var userID = $('#userID').val();
                if (challengeID != 0 && userID != 0) {
                    joinUserToChallenge(challengeID, userID);
                }
            });
```

I'm assuming this is because that function currently lives in the document.ready section, but I'm drawing a blank on how to integrate this into the JS file. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as always.

Comment: is the `#userJoin` field added after the page is loaded?  `.on()` won't recognize it if that's the case, and you'll have to bind to a parent element that loads with the page instead.

Comment: Well, it resides in the div that I'm calling: "newChallenge.html #challengeStuff" so, it shows up at the same time the page is loaded. Maybe, I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: That's just it though, ajax is asynchronous, so even though it,appears to be loafing at the same time, chances are its not. Especially if you've got it inside ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should work, if you put it in the callback for the ajax code that loads the content with your buttons.  `.on()` will only recognize elements that are in the DOM when the page is loaded, and won't catch inserted elements, unless you tag it to a parent that exists when the page is loaded.

However, creating the function and binding with the ajax callback should take care of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but here is a solution - how to attach event to specific element of loaded content:

```
$(ElementWhichContainsLoadedContent).on('click', 'ButtonSelector', function()
{
    // Your code
});
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

as I understood your problem correctly this the exact case where jQuery's `delegate` method should be used: [jQuery delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). Description from the documentation:

> Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, **now or in the future**, based on a specific set of root elements.

Before jQuery 1.7 there was a method called `live`, but now it is deprecated, so you should use `delegate`

Comment: `.on()` supercedes `.delegate()`, and binds the same way.  It will therefore work the same way in this instance.  The root problem still has to be addressed.  Either build your function after the element is inserted, or create a selector from a parent element.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch why `.delegate()` won't work in this case? can you explain in more details?

Comment: I can't explain it any more plainly than the documentation for `.delegate()` from jquery.com.  It says it in like three different ways in the first 3 paragraphs.  Particularly: "Passing and handling event data works the same way as it does for `.on()`."

Comment: sometimes I wonder why there are a couple methods in jQuery that does the same thing but with different arguments and different names

Comment: It's all in the pursuit of the most efficient solution. I'd expect some of these superceded selectors to be deprecated in future versions as well, but we'll see!  It always keeps you on your toes keeping up with it.